# How to spawn threads in pyobjc

Tags: python, grand-central-dispatch, pyobjc

I am learning how to use pyobjc for some basic prototyping. Right now I have a main UI set up and a python script that runs the main application. The only issue is when the script runs, the script runs on the main thread thus blocking the UI.

So this is my sample code snippet in that I attempted in python using the threading import:

```
def someFunc(self):
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        NSLog(u"Hello I am in someFunc")
        i = i + 1

@objc.IBAction
def buttonPress(self, sender):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threadedFunc)
    thread.start()

def threadedFunc(self):
    NSLog(u"Entered threadedFunc")
    self.t = NSTimer.NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats_(1/150., self,self.someFunc,None, True)
    NSLog(u"Kicked off Runloop")
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer_forMode_(self.t,NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

When clicking on the button, the NSLogs in `threadedFunc` prints out to console, but it never enters `someFunc`

So I decided to use NSThread to kick off a thread. On Apple's documentation the Objective-C call looks like this:

```
(void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)aSelector
                   toTarget:(id)aTarget
                 withObject:(id)anArgument
```

So I translated that to what I interpreted as pyobjc rules for calling objective-c function:

`detachNewThreadSelector_aSelector_aTarget_anArgument_(self.threadedFunc, self, 1)`

So in context the IBAction function looks like this:

```
@objc.IBAction
def buttonPress(self, sender):
    detachNewThreadSelector_aSelector_aTarget_anArgument_(self.threadedFunc, self, 1)
```

But when the button is pressed, I get this message: global name 'detachNewThreadSelector_aSelector_aTarget_anArgument_' is not defined.

I've also tried similar attempts with grand central dispatch, but the same message kept popping  up of global name `some_grand_central_function` is not defined

Clearly I am not understanding the nuances of python thread, or the pyobjc calling conventions, I was wondering if some one could shed some light on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the result that I wanted following the structure below. Like I stated in my response to the comments: For background thread, NSThread will not allow you to perform certain tasks. (i.e update certain UI elements, prints, etc). So I used `performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone_` for things that I needed to perform in between thread operations. The operations were short and not intensive so it didn't affect the performance as much. Thank you Michiel Kauw-A-Tjoe for pointing me in the right direction!

```
def someFunc(self):
    i = 0
    someSelector = objc.selector(self.someSelector, signature='v@:')
    while i < 20:
        self.performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone(someSelector, None, False)
        NSLog(u"Hello I am in someFunc")
        i = i + 1

@objc.IBAction
def buttonPress(self, sender):
    NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector_toTarget_withObject_(self.threadedFunc, self, 1)

def threadedFunc(self):
    NSLog(u"Entered threadedFunc")
    self.t = NSTimer.NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats_(1/150., self,self.someFunc,None, True)
    NSLog(u"Kicked off Runloop")
    self.t.fire()
```

Answer (score 0):

The translated function name should be

```
detachNewThreadSelector_toTarget_withObject_(aSelector, aTarget, anArgument)
```

You're currently applying the conversion rule to the arguments part instead of the Objective-C call parts. Calling the function with the arguments from your example:

```
detachNewThreadSelector_toTarget_withObject_(self.threadedFunc, self, 1)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still throws the error global name not defined.

Comment: It needs to be called from NSThread, but with a selector as the first argument:           `NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector_toTarget_withObject_(s, self, None)` where `s = objc.selector(self.threadedFunc, signature='v@:')`. If the function has one or more arguments or a return value, the signature should be different. More help on this can be found here -- http://lethain.com/how-to-use-selectors-in-pyobjc/

Comment: wow that was a stupid move on my part. Thanks for the help! However it still doesn't kick off the NSLoopRun portion of the `threadedFunc`. It enters `threadedFunc` and exits, but it seems to just skip `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats_ ` portion of it. And thanks for the resource. I will look in to that resource.

Comment: The NSTimer function also needs a selector as an argument, the link in the previous comment has the exact same function as an example.

Comment: I did model my structure based on the example on the site before my previous post and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I reproduced the NSTimer in NSThread code and am also getting no output. Calling either separately does give the expected results, so the problem seems to be combining them. Could it be that the thread output is not sent to standard out or NSLog? You might have better luck searching the regular Objective-C topics.

Comment: Hey Michiel, thanks for your input. I figured it out what it was. For background thread, NSThread will not allow you to perform certain tasks. (i.e update certain UI elements, prints, etc). So basically what I had to do was call `performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone_` on sections that were not doing what it was supposed to do. Thankfully the threads are not doing anything heavy duty and the call that I am making with  was a simple output so it didn't affect performance as much. I referred to this site: [link] (https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/threading-helpers.html)